# Symfony 4 correct way to configure "AppBundle" for entity Mapping

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I am following [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) documentation since I want to auto generate entity depending on the table in my database, and at the XML generation stage I am passing this line `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force DoctrineMappingBundle xml`. Since I dont have `AppBundle`, I created my own `DoctrineMappingBundle.php` in `src/Entity/`

My DoctrineMappingBundle.php looks like this

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class DoctrineMappingBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

It does generate the XML files, however when I run the entity generation command

`php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src`, it throws up this error

```
 In MappingException.php line 317:

 An error occurred in App\Entity\Entity\BlogComment
```

and

```
In AnnotationDriver.php line 60:
Class App\Entity\Entity\BlogComment does not exist
```

I am stuck at this point and I dont know why it could not generate the entity classes, and it seems to automatically add an extra `Entity` in the namespace but in my namespace Entity is only mentioned once in the namespace. I am not sure which configuration is causing this issue.

My `src` folder structure

```
src---------/
|--Controller/  
|--Entity--/
|-----DoctinemappingBundle.php 
|--Migrations/
|--Repository/ 
|--Kernel.php
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the docs make it clear that this functionality is no longer supported and if your read the [github issue](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/729) you will see why.

However the functionality is still there and your idea of using a fake bundle will work.  Just need the mapping bundle to be in the src directory.  And then a bit of copy/paste.

Here is a complete step by step approach to generating entities under S4.

```
// Install the software
mkdir mapping
cd mapping
composer create-project symfony/skeleton .
composer require orm-pack
// adjust DATABASE_URL in .env
```

Make a fake bundle for the mapping command:

```
// src/DoctrineMappingBundle.php
namespace App;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class DoctrineMappingBundle extends Bundle
{

}
// Add the bundle to config/bundles.php
App\DoctrineMappingBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
```

Now we are ready to make some entities:

```
// Generate the xml mappings
bin/console doctrine:mapping:import DoctrineMappingBundle xml
// Mapping files generated under src/Resources/config/doctrine

// Generate the entities
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
```

This generates the entities under src/App/Entity.  At this point you will want to copy the generated entities to src/Entity and then remove the App/Entity directory.  The namespace should already be correct.

Get rid of the mapping files by removing src/Resources as well.

This is as far as I took the exercise but you should be good to go.